# Creating array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I want to create an array of hashes in ruby as:

```
 arr[0]
     "name": abc
     "mobile_num" :9898989898
     "email" :abc@xyz.com

 arr[1]
     "name": xyz
     "mobile_num" :9698989898
     "email" :abcd@xyz.com
```

I have seen [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) and [array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) documentation. In all I found, I have to do something
like

```
c = {}
c["name"] = "abc"
c["mobile_num"] = 9898989898
c["email"] = "abc@xyz.com"

arr << c
```

Iterating as in above statements in loop allows me to fill `arr`. I actually rowofrows with one row like `["abc",9898989898,"abc@xyz.com"]`. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify this bit of your question: *I actually rowofrows with one row like like ["abc",9898989898,"abc@xyz.com"]*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming what you mean by "rowofrows" is an array of arrays, heres a solution to what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
array_of_arrays = [["abc",9898989898,"abc@xyz.com"], ["def",9898989898,"def@xyz.com"]]

array_of_hashes = []
array_of_arrays.each { |record| array_of_hashes << {'name' => record[0], 'number' => record[1].to_i, 'email' => record[2]} }

p array_of_hashes
```

Will output your array of hashes:

```
[{"name"=>"abc", "number"=>9898989898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}, {"name"=>"def", "number"=>9898989898, "email"=>"def@xyz.com"}]
```

Comment: Or even shorter, `array_of_hashes = array_of_arrays.collect{|each|Hash[%w{name number email}.zip(each)]}`

Comment: Nice one akuhn. I like that.

Answer (score 13):

you can first define the array as

```
array = []
```

then you can define the hashes one by one as following and push them in the array.

```
hash1 = {:name => "mark" ,:age => 25}
```

and then do

```
array.push(hash1)
```

this will insert the hash into the array . Similarly you can push more hashes to create an array of hashes.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it directly within the push method like this:

1. First define your array:

   `@shopping_list_items = []`
2. And add a new item to your list:

   `@shopping_list_items.push(description: "Apples", amount: 3)`
3. Which will give you something like this:

   `=> [{:description=>"Apples", :amount=>3}]`