# Ruby array of hashes unexpected behaviour

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I was trying to create an array of hashes, to which i have already found some excellent solutions here:

[Creating array of hashes in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725643/creating-array-of-hashes-in-ruby)

However while trying it out on my own, i found some behavior which i didn't understand.

Creating an array of hashes in IRB:

```
array_hashes = Array.new(7, Hash.new)
```

Now, on trying to assign key, value pairs to the array:

```
array_hashes[1]["hello"] = 200
```

I got the following output in console:

```
=>[{"hello"=>200}, {"hello"=>200}, {"hello"=>200}, {"hello"=>200}, {"hello"=>200}, {"hello"=>200}, {"hello"=>200}]
```

The same key , value was repeated across all the array elements, similar results when i tried to assign another key, value to a single array element

```
array_hashes[3]["world"] = 300
=>[{"hello"=>200, "world"=>300}, {"hello"=>200, "world"=>300}, {"hello"=>200, "world"=>300}, {"hello"=>200, "world"=>300}, {"hello"=>200, "world"=>300}, {"hello"=>200, "world"=>300}, {"hello"=>200, "world"=>300}]
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this, specifically why are hash values repeated across all the array elements even on being assigned to a single element.
Thanks!

> Ruby Version used: 1.9.3, tried on Windows 7 and OS X Yosemite

Comment: This has been asked many times before here on SO. The short answer is: read the docs for [`Array::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas), they even contain *the exact example* you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's repeated because what this code does:

```
array_hashes = Array.new(7, Hash.new)
```

Is this:

```
hash = Hash.new
array_hashes = [hash, hash, hash, hash, hash, hash, hash]
```

So it's the same object included 7 times in the array.

But what you wanted to do was:

```
array_hashes = Array.new(7) { Hash.new }
```